# Onesignal crash on boot with Android O

Tags: android, onesignal

With Android 0 (DP4 in my case) and the 3.5.8 version of **SDK**, I have a crash on every boot of the device.

The crash is the following :

Caused by:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not allowed to start service Intent { cmp=com.frandroid.app/com.onesignal.NotificationRestoreService (has extras) }: app is in background uid UidRecord{c74919a u0a125 RCVR idle procs:1 seq(0,0,0)}
 at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1505)
 at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1461)
 at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
 at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:644)
 at android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver.startWakefulService(WakefulBroadcastReceiver.java:100)
 at com.onesignal.BootUpReceiver.onReceive(BootUpReceiver.java:42)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3252)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap17(Unknown Source:0) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1677) 
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

This crash is related to Android O / 8.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been asked at the [One signal issues](https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Android-SDK/issues/274)

@jkasten2 answers:

```
// Add snapshots repo if you don't have it already
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }
    }


compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:4.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

He has also mentioned:

> From feedback from others and our own testing the beta has been stable. We are finishing our final testing and we are shooting for a release sometime next week.

Although the core issue is addressed by @Swati.

**Update:**

The ticket has been closed by OneSignal team, following is the fix (as updated in the [one signal documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v3.0/docs/android-sdk-setup)):

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:[3.6.0, 3.99.99]'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

WakefulBroadcastReceiver is deprecated in Android O -

"It is generally not safe to start a service from the receipt of a broadcast, because you don't have any guarantees that your app is in the foreground at this point and thus allowed to do so."

You might need to check https://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#back-all